# Install Windows 7 as virtual machine on Fedora 19

Tags: windows-7, operating-system, virtual-machine, fedora, virtualization

I have a personal computer on which I have dual operating systems installed.

One is Windows 7 and other is Fedora 19. I installed Fedora 19 after I installed Windows 7.

Now I want to use Windows 7 as virtual machine within Fedora 19 that I can run both operating systems concurrently.

Currently, I have to shutdown one operating system to use the other.

What is the process to install Windows 7 as virtual machine on Fedora 19? Or Can I convert the already installed Windows 7 as virtual machine into Fedora 19 on my PC?.

Hope the question does make some sense.

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to install a virtual machine host on your Fedora installation. Personally I prefer VirtualBox, and they have a decent guide to installation on Linux: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

Next you need to create a Virtual Machine. VirtualBox has a wizard to walk through this for you. During installation you will need either a Windows 7 installation disk in your drive, or a disk image (e.g. ISO) on your Fedora hard drive so that VirtualBox can use it to install Windows. For VirtualBox there is a useful guide in their manual: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#idp53897904

Once it's set up you just need to start the VM, and it will run the OS inside your other one, in a window of its own. Remember that your one machine now needs to run two OS's, so your performance will depend on how powerful your machine is - you can allocate more memory / CPU resources to the VM in the settings. (For VirtualBox: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#settings-system)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Chris, I want to virtualize window 7 in fedora because all I want that the webcam of my computer should do work seprately, which means, The web cam of host and guest should work independently as happens in seprate computer. The video streaming of both operating system should be seprate as happens in seprate computer. Is it possible if I virtualized the window 7 in fedora 19 successfully.

Comment: That's really completely different to the original question. It is possible to share hardware to the VM but I'm not certain if it needs certain requirements to be met first. I would say just try it.